# Cannot resolve symbol error while inserting my google maps api key

Tags: android-studio, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

[image]
when i try to change enter the api key it given a cannot resolve symbol error. Someone please help

Answer (score 1):

Please remove `"@string/"` from value attribute

**Replace**

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="@string/<Your-Api-Key>" />
```

**to**

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="<Your-Api-Key>" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put API key at the string reference which was present before.

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

And in your resources:

```
<string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">AIxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxWp_I</string>
```

Or you could just put the API as it as like this:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxWp_I" />
```